# How to open more than one app at a time in launchpad?

Tags: macos, applications, launchpad

Is there a way to open more than one app at a time in launchpad before it fades away?

I've tried holding down command, option, control, & shift in different configurations while clicking an app, but all that seems to do sometimes is to make launchpad very slowly fade out.

I like having my favorite apps on one screen, but launchpad is doubling the clicks needed to open apps as opposed to having them on the dock.

Using Lion btw.

Comment: I do not believe you can launch more then one app at a time from Launchpad. That said, if there is a group of apps you regularly want to open at the same time you could just make an app launcher using Automator and or AppleScript to open any number of specific apps at the same time. I do something similar, in that I have several webpages always open at the same time in the same window. This same concept could have been opening x number of application at the same time.

Comment: I second @user3439894 use a simple Automator app (if it's the same group of apps every time). Alternatively, you could have a keyboard shortcut that opens the applications folder (I think there might be one already?) and then `command` + click and `command`+`O`

Comment: You are correct, user3439894, it appears that the answer is "there is no way to do it, it's one app at a time." 

I'm finding a balance with having my most used apps on the taskbar for quick launching and using the launchpad for other apps less used. It does save searching thru the finder for things. Thanks for your help.

I like the idea of using the Automator for those "every morning" apps, thanks ruddfawcett, I'll give that a try too.

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to do it, it's one app at a time.